# unable to initialize iconpos for collapsible

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have a collapsible as a list item in a listview, in a jquery mobile application.

Since I am dynamically binding to the list via knockout I have handlers which take the responsibility of initializing the listview. Hence my markup is simple.

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1"> 
    <div  data-role="content">
        <ul id="mylist" data-bind="foreach: items, jqmRefreshList: items">
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2 data-bind="text: txt"></h2>
                    <p data-bind="text: desc"></p>
                </div>
            </li>            
        </ul>
    </div>    

</div>
```

The binding handler is written like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmRefreshList = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        try {
            console.log('executed');
            console.log(element);
            $(element).listview();
            var e = $(element).find('li >div');            
            e.collapsible({iconpos: "right"});
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
    }
};
```

In spite of the statement `e.collapsible({iconpos: "right"});` the collapsible element shows up with image on left, not right.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yxbv7h9g/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a quite old version (1.2) of jQuery mobile where the setting is called `iconPos` with an uppercase `P`:

```
var e = $(element).find('li >div');            
e.collapsible({iconPos: "right"});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdbs8e21/1/).

However this setting name changed in version [1.3.0](http://jquerymobile.com/changelog/1.3.0/) with fixing [#4899.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4899)

So if you upgrade your jQuery mobile version then your original code will also work: [Demo JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/dkzyvqs4/)

Comment: +1, or he can use the `data-iconpos="right"` attribute on the `div` element.

Comment: Yeah, setting iconpos from the data attribute would also work: http://jsfiddle.net/vdbs8e21/2/